# How much space mongodb documents take up internally during sort operations?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have a collection of documents where an average document takes up 2KB, checked via

```js
Object.bsonsize(db.getCollection('MyCollection').findOne({}))
```

while the collection total size is 5.84 mb checked via `db.getCollection('MyCollection').totalSize()`.

I'm doing the following aggregation:

```js
db.getCollection('MyCollection').aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "information.status": "active"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "OtherCollection",
      "localField": "a",
      "foreignField": "b",
      "as": "other"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$other"
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "totalMatchedCount": [
        {
          "$count": "count"
        }
      ],
      "items": [
        {
          "$sort": {
            "c": -1,
            "_id": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "$skip": 3210
        },
        {
          "$limit": 30
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$totalMatchedCount"
  }
])
```

where the size of `OtherCollection` is 0.48 mb. The aggregation fails with the error:

```
Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.
```

When I pass `allowDiskUse:true` option the [responseLength](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/#mongodb-data-system.profile.responseLength) of the aggregation is 0.16 mb.

So I'm just wondering how much space does mongodb take up for storing aggregation results internally? If the actual results size is 0.16 mb and the `allowDiskUse:true` error occurs if mongodb requires more than 100mb for sort operation this means that sort operation takes up at least 625 times more storage than the actual response. Does this make any sense? Importantly, no other queries/aggregations/operations were run during the above aggregation.

Comment: What is the response length if you leave out the `$skip` and `$limit`?